# CakePHP BlowFish Compare Password

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Inside my model User in beforeSave function I used blowfish to encrytp my password like this:

```
$passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
            );
```

But I don't know how can I decrypt it back in order to compare password with my custom login. Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first get the saved password,then you can use this

```
$newHash = Security::hash($current_pass, 'blowfish', $pass_stored);
```

then compare

```
$newHash === $pass_stored
```

here stored password used as a salt

Comment: I'd suggest to use **[`BlowfishPasswordHasher::check()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.7/class-BlowfishPasswordHasher.html#_check)** instead. In the end it's doing the same internally, and on top it's easier to change when upgrading to CakePHP 3.x, where `Security::hash()` won't work that way anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can never decrypt back. That is why it is secure.

When the user is created you Hash the password and store it in the database. Then when a user tries to login you Hash once more the password he entered. If this matches the one inside the database then the password is correct.

Simply the user in the registration enters password `12345` this hashes to `54321`. You should never know that he originally entered `12345`. So if he enters on login `12345` it will hash again to `54321` and this matches, so the password he entered is the correct one. If he enters a wrong password it will hash to something else (i.e. `53421`) so it will not match.

In linux bash you can use the following command to see that `1` will always has to the same

```
echo 1 | sha1sum
```

Comment: Using sha1 as an analogy doesn't really work - Using blowfish the hashed value of a given password is not always the same since the hashed value is also the salt.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check one password generated using BlowfishPasswordHasher you have to use the **Check** method

Imagine that we want to register a user with
username: mdiazr@yopmail.com and
password: 1234567

```
$password = '1234567';
$passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
$passwordEncrypted = $passwordHasher->hash($password);

$user['User'] = [
  'id' => '', 
  'username' => 'mdiazr@yopmail.com',
  'password' => $passwordEncripted 
]

$this->User->save(user)
```

In order to check that password in the login action

Having the credentials
username: mdiazr@yopmail.com
password: 1234567

```
/* Recover the encrypted password */
                        
if ($user = $this->User->find('first', ['conditions' => [
               'User.username' => 'mdiazr@yopmail.com',
          ]])) {
$passwordPlainText = '1234567'; 
$passwordEncrypted = $user['User']['password'];      
$passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
        
$checkResult = $passwordHasher->check($passwordPlainText, $passwordEncrypted );
        
if (!$checkResult) {
     /* Authentication failed */
   } else {
     /* Authentication success*/
   }    
}
```